# Keep pushing something

Tags: phrase-meaning

I faced that in the following:

> We were working together, we were exploring the concept of a dream
>   within a dream. I ***kept pushing*** things. I wanted to go deeper and
>   deeper, I wanted to go… further. I just didn’t understand the concept
>   that hours could turn into years down there. That we could get trapped
>   so deep that when we wound up on the shore of our own subconscious we
>   lost sight of what was real. We created, we built the world for
>   ourselves. We did that for years. We built our own world.

What could it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Kept pushing things" most nearly means "continued to work towards our goal [of going deeper]."

There's also this meaning of "continued to pursue despite overwhelming odds." It implies that "I" had to fight against problems or other people who didn't want him to "go deeper." In other words, it wasn't easy but he wanted it so he fought against those who were against him.